# How to rename a string within a column that contains a backslash in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a million row dataset, df,

```
  Name         

  \\tia@gmail.com\Out
  \\tia@gmail.com\Out
  \\tia@gmail.com\Out
  \\tia@gmail.com\In
  \\tia@gmail.com\In
  \\tia@gmail.com\In
```

I would like to replace all instances where \tia@gmail.com\Out occurs to Outboxdata. This is my desired output:

```
  Name

  Outboxdata
  Outboxdata
  Outboxdata
  \\tia@gmail.com\In
  \\tia@gmail.com\In
  \\tia@gmail.com\In
```

Here is the dput:

```
 structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label =       c("\\\\tia@gmail.com\\In", 
 "\\\\tia@gmail.com\\Out"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names   = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```

This is what I am starting with, I know I can use dplyr and gsub:

```
df %>%
   gsub,df$Name
```

I do not have the correct syntax, and I will continue to research this

Comment: Iin the expected, the In row remain as such, right?

Comment: My mistake! Oh yes sorry let me add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(Name = str_replace(Name, ".*[^A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]+)$", "\\1boxdata"))
#        Name
#1 Outboxdata
#2 Outboxdata
#3 Outboxdata
#4 Outboxdata
```

#### Update

If we want to replace only on strings having tia@gmail.com, then

```
df %>%
   mutate(Name = str_replace(Name, ".*tia@gmail.com\\\\+Out", "Outboxdata"))
```

---

Note: As we are replacing values in a particular column, use the function within `mutate`

Comment: Hi @Akrun, actually its changing every string that has \\ in front of it to 'Outboxdata'. Im only wanting \\tia@gmail.com\Out this to change to Outboxdata. I have some other data that is like\\tia@gmail.com\In that Id like to keep. Should I update my question?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Can you please update your post with the example and expected output

Comment: Yes @Akrun sorry for misunderstanding